# C# Таймер для множества

Tags: c#, .net

Есть список пользователей и нужно проверять онлайн статус, это обычно делают считая разницу во времени от последнего действия плюс некоторый интервал. DateTime.Now привязан ко времени установленном в системе и когда пользователь его сменит во время работы программы будут проблемы. Множество таймеров тоже на мой взгляд плохое решение. В общем как можно решать эту задачу? На данный момент у меня один таймер который каждую секунду отнимает у каждого объекта пользователя время сколько осталось до оффлайн в секундах

Comment: Синхронизировать время самостоятельно? http://worldclockapi.com/

Comment: Один таймер, интервал которого установлен на время самого последнего пользователя. При каждом срабатывании интервал меняется на новое самое последнее время.

Comment: Что-то я не думаю, что каждому юзеру дозволено менять время на системных часах. А если юзер - админ компа, то почему бы и нет. Неправильная работа софта тогда на его совести. На старте приложения сверяетесь с NTP сервером, и если UTC время отличается скажем сильнее, чем на 5 минут, выдаете ошибку, ну и в процессе работы приложения процедуру можно повторять. Это в теории. Потом есть вменяемый порок в разности "было-стало", если порог превышен или стал отрицательным, то это тоже индикатор, что что-то пошло не так.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4247026/12888024